# Chainlink Keeper: The execution failed due to an exception

Tags: blockchain, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

`Submit Registration request`

The execution failed due to an exception.

[image]

Trying to register my keeper contracts and getting this error. Has anyone navigated it? or should I just wait?

Comment: This means something wrong happened in your request. Could you please add what your request looks like?